# How to retrieve text value from a list box index in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

listbox1.items[0].tostring();

its the command for getting the text value of item at 0th index but i have some list boxes in my form which are data bound to a sql database table.When ever i use this command it gives me (System.Data.DataRowView) as a string as output regardless of the actual text value of the listbox item at 0th index.Plz guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Text property of the ListItem:

```
string itemText = ListBox1.Items[0].Text;
```

**Update:** 
 If you're in WinForms, a bound list box will return a DataRowView:

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)ListBox1.Items[0];
string itemText = drv.Row["MyColumn"].ToString();
```

Comment: are you sure this thing works because its not available in the pop up solutions panel when we type the commands

Comment: That was quite helpful dear but i had to make some changes to it with the command
string itemtext = drv.item["Column"].tostring();

instead i used 
string row2 = drv.Row["Time_End"].ToString();

Comment: Thanks now updated, I'm away from my development machine, I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: (DataRowView)listBox1.Items[0])["MyColumn"].ToString() is also working. Just to make it more simple.

Answer (score 2):

`.Text` no longer works as of 23/07/2013

Use `ListBox1.Items[index].ToString();`